# "Lamb" Use in Early British Modern English 17th-century 1608

Tags: british-english, early-modern-english, seventeenth-century-english

I am writing a screenplay set in England in the year 1608. In one sentence I used the word lamb (a young sheep), but according to what I've seen on the internet this term is more of a modern English. I came up with suggestions like lambkin or lambkinne that avoid the supposed anachronism, but I would like to know if "lamb" is employed wrong or not.

Comment: It looks like the word at least *existed* before then (see ngram result for 1500-1700, showing a spike in usage around 1560: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lamb%2Clambkin%2Clambkinne&year_start=1500&year_end=1700&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), but I'm not sure how reliable ngrams is for time periods earlier than the 1800s. This dictionary gives the earliest usage as "before the 12th century": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lamb

Comment: Your internet searches are steering you wrong. **Lamb** has been around since the Old English period, pre-Conquest.

Comment: _Lamb_ occurs frequently in the King James Bible.

Comment: [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/10/pg10.txt) KJV: Genesis "22:7 And Isaac spake unto Abraham his father, and said, My father: and he said, Here am I, my son. And he said, Behold the fire and the wood:
but where is the **lamb** for a burnt offering? 22:8 And Abraham said, My
son, God will provide himself a **lamb** for a burnt offering: so they
went both of them together." It's easy to find many different historical Bibles online should you want to research more thoroughly. (Coverdale has "shepe".)

Answer (score 3):

The word *lamb* was ussed in the early 16th century. The OP asked about the related word *lambkin*. In the early 16th century, *lambkin* (a diminutive of *lamb*) seems to have been more likely to to refer to a person as an animal, although it also could easily have been applied to a small lamb.

It occurs twice in Shakespeare's work:

In Henry IV Part ii:

> Sir John, thy tender lambkin now is King;

And in Henry V:

> Let us condole the knight; for, lambkins we will live.

In both, these references are to people.

In Shakespeare, *lamb* also can refer to people as well as animals, but its use for animals is fairly common.

Comment: According to Alexander Schmidt, _Shakespeare Lexicon and Quotation Dictionary_ (1902), Shakespeare uses _lamb_ in the sense of "the young of a sheep" at least 45 times and "as a term of endearment" 3 times—once in _Troilus and Cressida_ and twice in _Romeo and Juliet_.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the comments have referenced the King James Version of the Bible - it was published in 1611, and the translation work was mostly completed in 1608, so it's actually a great source for contemporary language at exactly the time you need (and, I guess, good to be aware of in general).

Regarding "lamb" specifically, a simple search of the Bible text finds 172 references, at least some of which are present in older translations as well. For example, John 1:29:

- KJV (1611) - Behold the Lamb of God, which taketh away the sin of the world.
- Tyndale (1534) - Beholde the Lambe of God which taketh away the synne of the worlde.

Answer (score 1):

Lamb has been used to mean "young sheep" since its inception in Old English. For an example near your time period (1617: [Aesop's fable, translated](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A08375.0001.001/1:4.2?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=A%20lamb)):

> ### Of a Wolfe and a Lamb
>
> A Wolfe drinking at the head of a spring, seeeth a lambe drinking farre beneath.

*Lambkin* was also in use at the time (c.f. [1614](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;didno=A16676.0001.001;g=eebogroup;rgn=full%20text;singlegenre=All;size=50;sort=occur;start=1;subview=detail;type=simple;view=reslist;xc=1;q1=Lambkin)), but with significantly less usage. It's also not an exact synonym, since it refers to a small lamb.

See also the [MED](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED25973) for older examples of "lamb".

Answer (score 0):

Lamb is Old English:

> OED
>
> Old English lamb, lambor (lǫmb, lǫmbor), lęmb strong neuter,
> corresponds to Old Saxon lamb.
>
> **1.a.The young of the sheep.** OE nixa est genuit agnam idest ceolbor lomb. *Corpus Glossary (Hessels) E 216*
>
> OE Muntas for hwon uphofun ge swe swe rommas & hyllas swe swe lomberu
> scepa. *Vespasian Psalter cxiii. 6*
>
> OE xx lamba & xx fehta. *Charter of Æthelberht in Old English Texts
> 438*